# How do I constrain UIView to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

Opposite of what everyone else seems to be asking. I have a collectionView with cells into which I am adding a loaded .xib as a subview. Easy enough.

However, the size of the collectionView cells change at run-time based on different criteria so I need the subview to be properly constrained to the size of the collectionViewCell's contentView. In an attempt to do this, I have this code when I add the subview:

```
/**
Used to present a view in the collectionView. WidetView is a subclass of UIView
*/
class WidgetCell: UICollectionViewCell, Reusable {
    var widgetView: WidgetView! {
        didSet {
            for view in contentView.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            contentView.addSubview(widgetView)
            let views = ["view": widgetView as Any]
            var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views)
            constraints.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views))

            contentView.addConstraints(constraints)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, what's presented isn't a set of views that are properly constrained. The added UIView is the same size as what's defined in the .xib.

[image: unsized cells]

How can I fix this?  If you want a sample project (Swift 3) look here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/FitToCell

Comment: Found my problem. I want to set the frame of the added UIView to match the contentView.frame, not use constraints.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, be warned however that doing it this way will mean that the frame won't update if you turn your device landscape, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Turns out the contentView isn't always the proper size. I need to pass the cell size into the WidgetCell class and set the widgetView.frame.size to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the expected size of the cell is known for layout purposes, pass that size to the WidgetCell instance and then set the view's frame size.

```
final class WidgetCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var cellSize: CGSize?
    var widgetView: WidgetView! {
        didSet {
            for view in contentView.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            let frame: CGRect
            if let cellSize = cellSize {
                frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: cellSize)
            } else {
                frame = contentView.frame
            }

            widgetView.frame = frame
            widgetView.setNeedsLayout()
            contentView.addSubview(widgetView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple case of calling `contentView.activateConstraints(constraints)` with your existing code and then at the point where the cells are shown, `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`. This forces the cell to recalculate the bounds of it's subviews.

Comment: A good idea and I looked into it. Newly added constraints are active by default and are activated/deactivated with the NSLayoutConstraint class. I did try the suggestion anyway of activating the constraints and setting a layoutIfNeeded when the collectionViewCell is being created and it didn't help. Try ideas on the project if you have any more.